# minesweeper setting values problem in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to make minesweeper in python.. i have problem with the search inside the cellgame..the random mines are working but the number per

## My Code

```
    #i search every shell for "nuke". When it finds it the perimeter became " 1 "
    def bottom(x,y):
        if table[x][y]=="nuke":
            table[x-1][y]=" 1  "
    def right(x,y):
        if table[x][y]=="nuke":
            table[x][y-1]=" 1  "
    def up(x,y):
        if table[x][y]=="nuke":
            table[x+1][y]=" 1  "
    def left(x,y):
        if table[x][y]=="nuke":
            table[x][y+1]=" 1  "






    #here I do the search
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            if table[x][y]!="nuke":
                    if x==0:
                      #here is the up left corner
                        if y==0:
                            right(x,y+1)
                            bottom(x+1,y)
                      #here is the up right corner
                        if y==10 :
                            bottom(x+1,y)
                            left(x,y-1)
                        else:
                      #the rest up
                            right(x,y+1)
                            bottom(x+1,y)
                            left(x,y-1)
                    elif x==10:
                      #here is the bottom left corner
                        if y==0:
                            up(x-1,y)
                            right(x,y+1)
                      #here is the bottom right corner
                        elif y==10:
                            left(x,y-1)
                            up(x-1,y)
                        else:
                      #the rest bottom
                            right(x,y+1)
                            left(x,y-1)
                            up(x-1,y)
                      #the rest
                    else:
                        right(x,y+1)
                        bottom(x+1,y)
                        left(x,y-1)
                        up(x-1,y)
```

for i in table:
        print i

## what my problem is: It's not working the part of searching and the count..do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Can you please break down your code on IDE and try small parts every time before running the whole thing? 

Comment: Please describe exactly *what* is not working.  Are you getting an error message?  An incorrect result?  Does your script get stuck in a loop?  Ideally, provide a [mcve] so we can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is my error  if table[x][y]=="nuke":                                                                                             IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: and ia make the table like that:
#insert  random for the bombs
import random
#insert data from the user (mine , number)
table=[]
number=100
mine=25
###############################
#i make the table of game
for i in range(number):
    table = [" "]*number
cellgame=["nuke"]* mine+[" "]*(number-mine)
bombs = ["nuke"] * mine + ["    "] * (number - mine)
random.shuffle(bombs)
table = [bombs[i:i+10] for i in range(0, number,10)]
#################################

Answer (score 0):

```
#i change somethin to the end
#i search every shell for "nuke". When it finds it the perimeter became " 1 "
def bottom(x,y):
    if table[x][y]=="nuke":
        table[x-1][y]=" 1  "
def right(x,y):
    if table[x][y]=="nuke":
        table[x][y-1]=" 1  "
def up(x,y):
    if table[x][y]=="nuke":
        table[x+1][y]=" 1  "
def left(x,y):
    if table[x][y]=="nuke":
        table[x][y+1]=" 1  "






#here I do the search
```

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        if table[x][y]!="nuke":
                if x==0:
                  #here is the up left corner
                    if y==0:
                        right(x,y-1)
                        bottom(x+1,y)
                  #here is the up right corner
                    if y==10 :
                        bottom(x+1,y)
                        left(x,y-1)
                    else:
                  #the rest up
                        right(x,y-1)
                        bottom(x+1,y)
                        left(x,y-1)
                elif x==10:
                  #here is the bottom left corner
                    if y==0:
                        up(x-1,y)
                        right(x,y+1)
                  #here is the bottom right corner
                    elif y==10:
                        left(x,y-1)
                        up(x-1,y)
                    else:
                  #the rest bottom
                        right(x,y+1)
                        left(x,y-1)
                        up(x-1,y)
                  #the rest
                else:
                    right(x,y-1)
                    bottom(x-1,y)
                    left(x,y-1)
                    up(x-1,y)